# MySql - CREATE TABLE `SortOrder` with Foreign Key constraint?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

This is a table that would be used by any other table that needs to make use of it. As such, imagine LARGE amounts of use.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `sortorder` (
  `sortOrderId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sortOrder` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sortOrderId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

What would be needed to make sure that this table can handle whatever LOAD is thrown at it?

I can only imagine needing a `tinyint datatype` for the `sortOrder` for example if I have 10 tabs in a menu, or 5 thumbnail images etc, then you can see we would not need a large INT datatype here.

The other thing that I need to learn and do is set a Foreign Key constraint on this table.

If the `image` table for example deletes a record with a `sortOrderId` the matching record needs to be deleted in the `sortorder` table.

How is this done?

ALTER TABLE sortorder code:

```
ALTER TABLE sortorder ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_sortorder;
```

CREATE TABLE sortorder code:

```
...
```

**EDIT: `image` table using a `sortOrderId` column.
I MUST ensure that if a record is deleted in `image` table - the corresponding record is deleted in `sortorder` table.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `image` (
  `imageId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imageFileName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagePath` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageTitle` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageAlt` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageWidth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageHeight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageSizeId` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `isImageEnabled` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `sortOrderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to making this table fast to use [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) on the columns that you will select and sort on if they have a high cardinality. You should probably add key on sortOrder if you think there will be a high level of variance on this key.

---

To get the `cascade delete` you will need this:

```
ALTER TABLE sortorder
   add CONSTRAINT fk_sortOrderId
     FOREIGN KEY (sortOrderId)
     REFERENCES image(sortOrderId)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
```

---

I think an index on the `sortOrder` will not be very effective. This is due to the nature of the BTree datastructure that the indexes are composed with. If you think about it most values for `sortOrder` will likely be low number 1-10. With little variance the benefits of the index goes down.

It seems you will be better off using a composite index.

```
CREATE INDEX `sort_index` on `sortorder` (`sortOrderId`, `sortOrder`)
```

You will have to monitor the performance during runtime to really get a feel of this is the right way to get the most of your database, I am only guessing.

Comment: is there an ALTER TABLE syntax I should use to create and set the Foreign Key?

Comment: @jojo foreign key? I think you just want an `index` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html if it is a foreign key you should post your other table

Comment: `CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name` - what kind of INDEX should `sortOrder` be?